# execCommand("bold") when text is between symbols

Tags: editor, markdown, execcommand

I want to create a very simple markdown editor with `contentEditable` and `execCommand`. I can only find examples where you select a text and press a button to make the selected text bold (or other stuff). But I would like to be able to write `**bold text**` and that it automatically makes the text between ** bold. Same like the editor from stackoverflow, but I don't want the ** to be removed. They should still be there, but maybe in another style.  I don't know how to do it. Do you do that with Regex or how?

Comment: `contentEditable` is for rich text. What you're looking for is something like https://codemirror.net/mode/markdown/

Comment: @mb21 Yes, something like that. But how do I do it?

Comment: uh, start by reading the codemirror documentation? once, you have a more specific question, stackoverflow might be a better fit. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask